# IIS 7 host headers : bind multiple subdomain addresses to an application

Tags: iis

I have a server with a single IP, two applications in my IIS, both have their domains (aaa.aa, bbb.bb). Each application should be accessible from vide range of subdomains, so request for 11.aaa.aa goes to the first app, and 11.bbb.bb to the second. I planned to do that via IIS Host Headers, but it seems you can specify only one address at a time (while I can't fill in every subdomain)... So I'm wondering, can I do that? Any suggestion would be appreciated as I'm stuck right now... Thanks.

Comment: You can do that in IIS 10 when it comes out in 2016

Answer (score 0):

No, you  can specify many address at a time.

Just go in Bindings section ed set them.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I need to set a range of subdomain addresses using a single record, like *.bbb.bb. I'm quite surprised iis bindings does not allow do use such a format.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of control you have. I don't think there is a way to have a wildcard host header binding in IIS7.

You could give the machine two IP addresses, setup site A with one address and site B with the other IP address. Don't specify any host header.

Then you can use DNS to control which IP your domain / sub domain points to.

e.g.

IIS Bindings

```
Site 1 - 192.168.0.1
Site 2 - 192.168.0.2
```

DNS

```
*.aaa.aa  192.168.0.1
*.bbb.bb  192.168.0.2
```

Comment: Yes, this can be a solution, I'll try it out